# Firefox does not show in Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-uninstall

I had trouble with Firefox and could not find it to uninstall it. Why don't I see it in Ubuntu Software? I added another FF and it shows in Ubuntu Software, but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: It my be installed via apt or it may be installed via snap (or both).

Comment: You did not say what version of Ubuntu. What is the actual problem with Firefox? The problem may have nothing to do with the browser but who can tell from what you have wrote here.